# How to emulate quadbuffer stereo with framebuffers and nvapi?

Tags: c++, opengl, stereo-3d

I am trying to do stereoscopic 3D with opengl on a later model GTX cards. The answer by datenwolf to a a prior question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918945/how-to-do-stereoscopic-3d-with-opengl-on-gtx-560-and-later) indicated that it was possible to emulate quadbuffer stereo using NVision3D API, which I think is now part of the NVIDIA api (nvapi).  I have downloaded the api and documentation, and I do see some calls for stereo 3D, but it is not at all clear how to do the stereo 3D emulation which datenworld referred to.  Can anybody provide a c++ code example of how to use the nvapi to do stereo 3D emulation with framebuffers and blitting to nvapi?

Comment: Yes, I didn't forget you. The problem is, that my main development machine doesn't host a NVidia GPU ATM; also I don't own a set of NVidia 3DVision glasses, so I can't test anything I'd write.

Comment: I'll test it for you and post a working version.  I'm just looking for the general idea.  Just some really high level pseudocode would probably be enough.

Answer (score 0):

There are few postings on the '[meant to be seen 3d](http://www.mtbs3d.com)' forums

How to drive the [NVidia USB transmitter](http://www.mtbs3d.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=3130)  directly

I can't find it but there is also code somewhere on there that generates the directX stereo screen image. Basically you create a double width left-rigth image on a directX surface, add a magic word to the end of the buffer and the driver does the rest.  It worked a year ago when I played with it.

Why NVidia (the openGL company) only supports Directx is anyones guess!

Comment: They consider OpenGL quadbuffer stereo a "professional" feature, and make it available to only the Quadro GPUs. But that's purely a software thing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot used quad-buffered mode with OpenGL on GeForce cards without an API key from nVidia. Only Direct3D quad-buffered is free.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?